# Can I sort records by child record count with DataMapper (without using raw SQL)?

Tags: sql, datamapper

What I want to do feels pretty basic to me, but I'm not finding a way to do it using DataMapper without resorting to raw SQL. That would look something like:

```
select u.id, u.name, count(p.id) as post_count
from posts p
inner join users u on p.user_id = u.id
group by p.user_id
order by post_count desc;
```

The intention of the above query is to show me all users sorted by how many posts each user has. The closest I've found using DataMapper is `aggregate`, which doesn't give me back resource objects. What I'd *like* is some way to generate **one** query and get back standard DM objects back.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have relationships

```
has_n, :posts
```

you should be able to do

```
User.get(id).posts.count
```

or

```
User.first(:some_id => id).posts.count
```

or

```
u = User.get(1)
u.posts.count
```

you can also chain conditions

```
User.get(1).posts.all(:date.gt => '2012-10-01')
```

see scopes and chaining here http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html

finally add the ordering

```
User.get(1).posts.all(:order => [:date.desc])
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer; but unless I'm missing something, this doesn't tell me how to *sort* by child record *count*, does it? That is fundamentally my question—i.e., based on your examples, how would I get *all users* sorted by *posts per user*? (Presumably something like `User.all(:order => { :posts => :count })` or something like that, though that obviously doesn't work.)

Comment: That works if you are tracking post count in the user object which is fairly trivial to do.  User.all(:order => {:post_count.desc}).  This may be easier on your database overall, you just need to increment when you add a post.

Comment: I agree that it would be trivial and that it may be easier on the database. However, I don't *think* (with proper indexing) it should really have a significant impact on performance; and more importantly, I'd rather not be forced into a specific database design simply to accommodate a particular ORM! Doesn't that seems a little backwards?

Comment: you might be able to do User.get(1).posts.all(:fields =>[:user_id])   this would require you to embed the user id in the post model vs using a resource table.  :fields triggers group_by